# minimum sum of x contiguous elements in an array

Tags: algorithm, minimum

I know the linear time algorithm to solve this problem, where you add the next element to, and the last element from the current sum. I'd like to know if there's a faster method to solve this problem.

Comment: How would you solve the problem is less than O(n)? You need to at least look at all n elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take e.g. array with negative numbers. To solve your problem you should add all of them. So lower limit of complexity of this problem is O(n).